# How to add content to an http request?

Tags: php, html, http, header

I have the following:

```
$request="HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sat, 04 Sep 2010 00:37:36 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Cache: MISS from proxy.rstel.net
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxy.rstel.net:3128
Via: 1.0 proxy.rstel.net (squid/3.0.STABLE15)
Proxy-Connection: close

<html>
<body>
Blah Blah Blah
</body>
</html>"

$response=addhtml("Hello world!",$response);
```

How to add a custom html above the `<html>` right there? I want a solution based on the blank line gap!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In zend framework there is some something like that

```
$this->getResponse()
             ->appendBody("Hello World\n")
```

I wonder why you have Hello World 2 times. With addhtml you want to add custom text to response  or append.